# How to monitor tags of a Github repo?

Tags: github

Is there an app or something to monitor Github repos' tags so it sends a notification if there is a new version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup a [GitHub webhook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) in order to monitor [create events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#createevent).

That will alert you for any branch or tag created on that GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch the repo and Github will notify you of activity in that repo. You can configure how you receive notifications on your Github profile's notification settings.